# Consumo de memoria al procesar archivo .csv

Tags: python, csv, manejo-de-memoria

Lo primero agradecer si alguien se toma la molestia de leer la pregunta y segundo advertir que soy novato total. Estoy haciendo esto por hobby.

Estoy haciendo un programa para realizar consultas en archivos .csv muy grandes con registros de diferentes puntos de medida cada 15 minutos todos los días del mes. Este archivo original pesa unos 650-700 MB.

El caso es que para hacer más fácil las consultas lo primero que hago es dividir los archivos con los registros mensuales en archivos más pequeños con las lecturas separadas por días con este código:

```
def separa_fechas(lista):
    if(True): #aqui en algún momento irá una verificación
        if(len(lista)==10): #Si tiene identif, lo quitamos
            lista.pop(2)

        if(len(lista)==9): #ya estaríamos con la lista en formato inicial.
            for i in range(len(lista)):
                aux=lista[i]
                aux2=aux.replace(chr(34), "") #hacemos esto porque en algunos conjuntos de datos todos los campos aparecen entrecomillados
                lista[i]=aux2

            fecha_comillas=lista[1] #el string fecha va a conservar las comillas, se las quitamos (esto es redundante con lo anterior, lo dejamos porque mal no hace)
            fecha=fecha_comillas.replace(chr(34), "") #reemplazamos " por un espacio vacio, como no se puede nombrar " usamos la funcion chr y el codigo de las comillas, 34
            lista_aux=fecha.split(" ")
            lista_dia=lista_aux[0].split("-") #aqui tenemos el dia [yyyy, mm, dd], ojo, como str
            lista_hora=lista_aux[1].split(":") #aqui tenemos la hora [hh, mm, ss], ojo, como str

            #Ahora componemos la lista nueva que va a devolver, pasamos a entero los datos correspondientes ya que salen de la linea del archivo como strings
            lista_return=[int(lista[0]), int(lista_dia[0]), int(lista_dia[1]), int(lista_dia[2]), int(lista_hora[0]), int(lista_hora[1]), lista[2], int(lista[3]), int(lista[4]), int(lista[5]), int(lista[6]), lista[7], int(lista[8])]

        return lista_return

    else:
        print("Algo ha ido mal con los datos :(")


datos=open(ruta, "r") 

contador=0 

for i in datos:
    if contador==0: #nos saltamos la primera linea del archivo, la de las definiciones
        contador+=1
        next

    else: 
        contador+=1
        lista=i.split(";") #Transformamos cada linea del archivo en lista

        lista_fecha=separa_fechas(lista) #generamos una nueva lista con la fecha separada :)

        ruta_main=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        ruta_carpeta=genera_ruta_carpeta(lista_fecha[1],lista_fecha[2],ruta_main) #nos devolverá "Directorio del main"\\Datos trafico\\mes_en_letra añoYYYY

        if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta): #Comprueba la existencia de la carpeta y si no existe la crea.
            os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta)


        ruta_archivo=genera_ruta_archivo(lista_fecha[1], lista_fecha[2], lista_fecha[3], ruta_main) #"Directorio del main"\Datos trafico\Mes_en_letra YYYY\YYYY-MM-DD

        #Ahora que tenemos la ruta del archivo comprobamos si existe o no el fichero diario con la funcion path.exists(file) que devuelve True si file existe
        if os.path.exists(ruta_archivo):
            resumen_diario=open(ruta_archivo, "a")
            resumen_diario.write("\n")
            resumen_diario.write(str(lista_fecha))
            resumen_diario.close()

        else:
            resumen_diario=open(ruta_archivo, "w")
            resumen_diario.write(str(lista_fecha))
            resumen_diario.close()

datos.close()
```

El caso es que procesando los archivos en ocasiones windows da error diciendo algo así como que se ha quedado sin memoria (no he guardado el pantallazo y la cosa tarda bastantes horas, pero si es necesario lo hago y lo pongo).

No entiendo muy bien de donde viene el consumo tan desaforado de datos ya que, como mucho, tiene que cargar el fichero grande en memoria una vez, pero a partir de ahí abre y cierra los archivos más pequeños.

Estoy pensando en soluciones y de momento se me ocurren 2:

1. Trocear el archivo grande en otros más pequeños y hacer el mismo proceso con esos archivos más pequeños.
2. Utilizar un puntero y abrir y cerrar el archivo grande para ir accediendo a las sucesivas líneas.

¿Cuál pensáis que puede funcionar mejor? ¿Hay alguna otra solución más efectiva?

Gracias

Comment: @Miguel_Barreiro Este código no está completo. Normalmente, necesitamos un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Mirando posibles fallas, necesitaríamos ver la función `separa_fechas`.

Comment: Ah, perdón, cosas del ser novato. Ya está incluído.

Comment: Miguel he mirado el código por encima y no veo dónde puede estar el problema, hay cosa que se pueden mejorar en especial si tu fichero de partida está ordenado por fecha. No obstante en ningún momento se carga todo el archivo en memoria al completo, lo procesas línea a linea.. Por cierto el condicional y el contador no son necesarios para nada, con hacer `next(datos)` después de `open` ya consumes la primera línea del fichero y puedes pasar al `for i in datos:`. Lo miraré con más detenimiento cuando tenga un pc mano, con lo que muestras no veo ahora nada que justifique un uso intensivo de RAM.

Comment: Gracias por lo del next, lo probaré.

Para ponerle un poco de contexto, he hecho un contador al recorrer el archivo, que no lo había hecho hasta ahora, y me sale que tiene más o menos 10.000.000 líneas.

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Ya veo cuál es tu problema. No obstante, corrije la identación del código ya que, supongo, el `for i in datos` va fuera de la función `separa_fechas`.

Comment: Si, va fuera, estoy intentando corregir la identación pero, no sé si por problemas con mi navegador, me está siendo bastante imposible :(

Comment: @MiguelBarreiro Para pegar código correctamente indentado en StackOverflow, símplemente abre tu editor de código favorito, asegúrate de que el código esté bien indentado en el editor, copia el código, pégalo en la pregunta en el navegador, y entonces selecciona todo el texto que has copiado y pincha el botón `{}` que tienes en la barra de botones de la caja de texto donde escribes. Eso añadirá cuatro espacios delante de cada línea, y hará que se visualice correctamente como código.

Comment: @MiguelBarreiro Este código no debería tardar mucho en procesar los 700 MB de tu fichero. Si dices que tarda varias horas es porque lo estás aplicando a varios ficheros en cadena. ¿Hay más código que el que nos estás enseñando? ¿Cuáles son las condiciones con las que ejecutas el código (RAM, CPU,...)?¿Has probado con otros sistemas operativos? No obstante, este código se puede optimizar mucho, incluso paralelizarlo para que sea más rápido. Como consejo general: nunca cambies los elementos de una lista que viene como argumento de entrada de una función.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias! Creo que el identado está ya bien.

Comment: @ChemaCortes 

No entiendo lo de los varios ficheros en cadena. El fichero de origen es uno y los de salida deberían ser entre 28 y 31 que se van abriendo y cerrando para añadirles una línea.

El código para esta función es este, no hay más.

Las condiciones, lo estoy ejecutando en un i5-2410M con 8 GB de Ram sobre windows 7, he probado con otro ordenador más moderno, un i7 con 16 GB de RAM y windows 10 y tarda algo menos.

Y por último, lo de cambiar elementos de una lista que viene como argumento tampoco lo acabo de entender.

Gracias en cualquier caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias estrategias posibles, pero habría que saber más de la naturaleza de los datos.

Por lo que dices en los comentarios, para cada registro se abre y cierra el fichero para escribir un dato en él. Este tipo de operaciones de entrada/salida son muy lentas en comparación con el tiempo que se emplea en los cómputos. Posiblemente, las pruebas que has hecho con i5 y i7 se diferencien más en el disco duro que en la velocidad de la CPU.

Intenta reducir el número de accesos a disco. Lo más sencillo es preparar los datos en un diccionario y volcarlo cuando esté listo:

```
dirs = set()  # set con los directorios para crear
data = {}  # diccionario para preparar los datos

for i in datos:
  ...
  ...
  ruta_carpeta = genera_ruta_carpeta(lista_fecha[1],lista_fecha[2],ruta_main)
  dirs.add(ruta_carpeta)

  ruta_archivo = genera_ruta_archivo(lista_fecha[1], lista_fecha[2],
                                     lista_fecha[3], ruta_main)
  data[ruta_archivo] = lista_fecha

for ruta_carpeta in dirs:
  if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta):
    os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta)

for (ruta_archivo, lista_fecha) in data.items():
  with open(ruta_archivo, "a") as resumen_diario:
    resumen_diario.write(str(lista_fecha))
```

Nota que no hace falta distinguir entre los modos *append* y *write* al abrir el fichero, ya que el modo *append* crea el fichero si no existe, igual que lo haría el modo *write*.

Espero que se note mejoría. Otra posibilidades sería usar multiproceso, para lo que habría que particionar los datos (por ejemplo, en función de la fecha de obtención).

---

**Editado**: Corrección y mejora del código

Tal como está, tiene el problema de que en el diccionario `data` para guardar los datos no guarda bien todos los datos. Cuando se hace la asignación `data[ruta_archivo] = lista_fecha` se machaca el valor antiguo con el nuevo.

Una forma habitual de solucionar esto es usando *defaultdicts*:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)  # diccionario para preparar los datos
                          # con list como constructor por defecto

for i in datos:
    ...
    ...
    data[ruta_archivo].append(lista_fecha)
```

Ahora mismo, como items en el diccionario tenemos listas de valores, por lo que tenemos que cambiar un poco el bucle que escribe en los ficheros:

```
for (ruta_archivo, listas_fechas) in data.items():
  with open(ruta_archivo, "a") as resumen_diario:
    for lista_fecha in listas_fechas:
      resumen_diario.write(lista_fecha)
```

Hay que hacer notar que el fichero sólo se abre una vez para escribir todos los valores, en lugar de una vez para cada valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Hay cosas que no entiendo demasiado bien pero con tiempo y paciencia las iré incorporando, sin duda mejorarán el rendimiento.

En cuanto al problema de memoria, ya está resuelto. Hice una versión que partía el archivo CSV en partes más pequeñas pero me seguía dando error por el consumo de memoria pero el problema era mucho más peregrino, estaba ejecutando el script desde el REPL de Sublime... Ejecuté el script desde el .py y el consumo de memoria bajó drásticamente además de hacer más rápido el proceso (un par de horas)

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto el problema.

El fallo estaba en que ejecutaba el script desde el REPL de Sublime y esto por algún motivo que desconozco dispara el consumo de memoria.

Ejecutando el script desde el .py el consumo de memoria era significativamente menor y el proceso mucho más rápido.

Muchas gracias a todas las personas que han contestado.

Salud